# Use polynomial expansion for $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ centered a x=0 with an error less than 0.001

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$

What I got is:

$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}...$ and multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{x}$ I get:

$\frac{\sin x}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}...$

Now, how do I approximate to that error? Any help or tip would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the Taylor remainder theorem? That supplies estimates for the error in a truncated Taylor series.

Comment: What interval around $x=0$?

Comment: @Semiclassical yeah, we've done some examples last year, but usually without a fraction, so $|sin(x)|≤1$

Comment: @Henry just around x=0

Comment: The interval $[-0.05,0.05]$ is around $x=0$ and the polynomial $1$ has an error less than $0.001$ on that interval.  The interval $[-5,5]$ is also is around $x=0$ and the polynomial $1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+\frac{x^8}{9!}-\frac{x^{10}}{11!}+\frac{x^{12}}{13!}-$ has an error greater than $0.001$ on parts of that interval.

Comment: @Semiclassical usually we would have a specified x, so for example $sin(2)$ and an interval. This is a new example to me. If you could give a hint I would appreciate it